# How to expand a range of values to individual values separated by commas in MS Excel 2007 and 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, range

How to expand a range of values to individual values separated by commas?

Example 1:

convert `R1-R8` TO `R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8`
1-10 TO 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

I need these expanded range to be comma separated and placed in one cell.
Is there a formula that can do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This VBA code will do the work:

```
Public Function sequence(data As String)
    result = ""
    endvalues = Split(data, "-")
    minval = endvalues(0)
    maxval = endvalues(1)
    lminval = Len(minval)
    lmaxval = Len(maxval)
    For i = 1 To lminval
        singlechar = Mid(minval, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(singlechar) = True Then
            minchar = Left(minval, i - 1)
            minnum = Right(minval, lminval - (i - 1))
            i = lminval
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To lmaxval
        singlechar = Mid(maxval, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(singlechar) = True Then
            maxchar = Left(maxval, i - 1)
            maxnum = Right(maxval, lmaxval - (i - 1))
            i = lminval
        End If
    Next i
    For i = minnum To maxnum
        result = result & minchar & i & ","
    Next i
    result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    sequence = result
End Function
```

Open Macros /VBA, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a module and paste it on the right side of the window.

If on cell `A1`you have for example *R1-R5* then on cell `B1`you can put `=sequence(A1)` to get the result *R1,R2,R3,R4,R5*